# Scrapy cannot find spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am doing scrapy tutorial in [scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/tutorial.html) .
This is my current directory looks like:

```
.
├── scrapy.cfg
└── tutorial
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── items.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    └── spiders
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        └── dmoz_spider
```

The dmoz_spider.py is the same as described in scrapy tutorial page.

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Then I run this command from current directory

```
scrapy crawl dmoz
```

But I get the error message:

```
2015-12-17 12:23:22 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-12-17 12:23:22 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-12-17 12:23:22 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
    ...
        raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
    KeyError: 'Spider not found: dmoz'
```

Is there any suggestions which part did I do wrong?
I have checked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152473/scrapy-python-cannot-find-the-spider) in stack overflow and follow the solution there. But I still get the error.

Comment: can you share what outputs for `scrapy list`, and also from which folder are you running this

Comment: I run the command from the directory that contains scrapy.cfg. I tried to run scrapy list, it shows nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a `.py` extension to your `dmoz_spider` file. The file name should be `dmoz_spider.py`.

Comment: Thanks. Never thought it is the problem